# Where is response_delete()?

Tags: django, django-admin

There're two methods in ModelAdmin response_add and response_change. But I need also to add behavior for the situation when user deletes object from change-form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's not currently a feature, but it is seemingly going to be added.](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20558)